# Check Scrollbar Visibility

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scrollbar, visibility

Is there a way to check if the Vertical Scroll Bar is visible on a certain ListView object?

I got a Windows Forms with a listView on it, on the resize event i would like to catch if the listview has its Vertical Scroll Bar visible!

Comment: @thephpdeveloper I don't believe he means ListView object...but rather the actual ListView, reverting it back...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is WPF a [sample exist](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/anshulee/archive/2008/03/26/wpf-figure-out-dynamically-if-the-listview-scrollviewer-is-showing.aspx) here which at the base of the solution hooks on to `ListView.LayoutUpdated`.

If this is WinForms you could make use of pinvoke and [GetWindowLong](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowlong)...

```
  static public class WndInfo
  {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    ...
    public static bool IsWindowTopMost(IntPtr Handle)
    {
      return (GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOPMOST) != 0;
    }
    ...
  }
```

[VB code exists](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299686#appliesto) using `GetWindowLong` to check if a ScrollBar exist which you could port to C#.

Comment: @Cloaky - best to write down as much details in your question as possible. you can click on the edit link to edit your question =)

Comment: No you didn't... there's still nothing in the question to specify that you are talking about Windows Forms. I assumed you were talking about WPF as well.

Comment: Question is, do you actually _need_ that information? If it's to fit columns, you're better off just using ClientRectangle; it always gives the usable area inside the scrollbars.

Comment: Please update broken link

Comment: C# code to check ScrollBars visibility https://www.csharp-examples.net/check-scrollbars-visibility/

Answer (score 2):

I have several methods that I use when using Winforms that are based on what type of control I would like to get that information from. Here is my class.

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    const Int32 LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    const Int32 LVM_SCROLL = LVM_FIRST + 20;

    [DllImport("user32")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr Handle, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


    // offset of window style value
    const int GWL_STYLE = -16;

    // window style constants for scrollbars
    const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000;
    const int WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);


    static ScrollBars GetControlVisibleScrollbars(Control ctl)
    {
        int wndStyle = GetWindowLong(ctl.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
        bool hsVisible = (wndStyle & WS_HSCROLL) != 0;
        bool vsVisible = (wndStyle & WS_VSCROLL) != 0;

        if(hsVisible)
            return vsVisible ? ScrollBars.Both : ScrollBars.Horizontal;
        else
            return vsVisible ? ScrollBars.Vertical : ScrollBars.None;
    }

    public static ScrollBars GetVisibleScrollbars(this ListView lv)
    {
        if(lv is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lv));
        }

        return GetControlVisibleScrollbars(lv);
    }


    public static ScrollBars GetVisibleScrollbars(this ScrollableControl ctl)
    {
        if(ctl is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ctl));
        }

        if(ctl.HorizontalScroll.Visible)
            return ctl.VerticalScroll.Visible ? ScrollBars.Both : ScrollBars.Horizontal;
        else
            return ctl.VerticalScroll.Visible ? ScrollBars.Vertical : ScrollBars.None;
    }


    private static void ScrollHorizontal(Form form, int pixelsToScroll)
    {
        SendMessage(form.Handle, LVM_SCROLL, (IntPtr)pixelsToScroll, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public static void EnsureVisible(this ListViewItem item, int subItemIndex, int margin=10)
    {
        if(item is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        }

        if( subItemIndex > item.SubItems.Count - 1)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"ListView {item.ListView.Name} does not have a SubItem on index {subItemIndex}");
        }

        // scroll to the item row.
        item.EnsureVisible();
        Rectangle bounds = item.SubItems[subItemIndex].Bounds;
        bounds.Width = item.ListView.Columns[subItemIndex].Width;
        ScrollToRectangle(item.ListView,bounds,margin);
    }



    private static void ScrollToRectangle(ListView listView, Rectangle bounds, int margin)
    {
        int scrollToLeft = bounds.X + bounds.Width + margin;
        if(scrollToLeft > listView.Bounds.Width)
        {
            ScrollHorizontal(listView.FindForm(),scrollToLeft - listView.Bounds.Width);
        }
        else
        {
            int scrollToRight = bounds.X - margin;
            if(scrollToRight < 0)
            {
                ScrollHorizontal(listView.FindForm(),scrollToRight);
            }
        }
    }
```

Say in your use case you have a splitter panel and you would like to have the left panel wide enough not to have a horizontal scrollbar then you could do this:

```
var bar= MyListView.GetVisibleScrollbars();
while(bar== ScrollBars.Horizontal || bar== ScrollBars.Both)
{
    progressPanels.SplitterDistance += 5;
    bar = MyListView.GetVisibleScrollbars();
}
```

I'm not saying it's the best way, I just say it's an option, especially if dealing with several monitors in different DPI